# Bugs while testing react for asynchronous tasks, Unable to find an element by: \[data-testid="reload-button"\]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-testing

** Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="reload-button"]**

Facing issues when testing a create-react-app using RTL.

I've a simple react project wherein I'm making a call over the internet to display a list of users. While writing a testcase for the same, I'm trying to mock a fetch call and provide dummy data as well so that my app doesn't increase load on the server.

But I'm facing issues in this.

I get an error saying:

`Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="reload-button"]

```
Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
<body>
  <div />
</body>

  15 |     render(<Body  />)
  16 |
> 17 |     await waitFor(()=>expect(screen.getByTestId("reload-button")))
     |                  ^
  18 |     const usersArray = screen.getAllByTestId("users-list")
  19 |     expect(usersArray.length).toBe(5)
  20 | })

  at waitForWrapper (node_modules/@testing-library/react/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/wait-for.js:166:27)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/__tests___/Body.test.js:17:18)`
```

My code is as follows:

The  component where an api call is made, using which the state is changed and data is passed on to the  as props

```
//Body.js

const Body = () => {
    const [ users, setUsers ] = useState([])
    const  [ reloadUsers , setReloadUsers] = useState(false)
    useEffect(() =>{
        fetchUsers()
    },[reloadUsers])

    const fetchUsers = async () => {
        const data = await fetch(`https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5`) 
        const jsonData = await data.json()
        setUsers(jsonData?.results)
    }
    if(!users)return null

    return users.length===0 ? <p>Loading...</p> :  (
        <div>
            <button 
               data-testid='reload-button' 
               onClick={()=> setReloadUsers(prev => !prev) } >
               Load different users
            </button>
            <UserList users={users}  />
        </div>
      )
}
```

The  component receiveing the data as props and then mapping over it to display the data

```
//UserList.js

const UserList = ({users}) => {
    const displayList = users.map(user=>(
        <li data-testid="users-list"  
            style={{'display' : 'flex' , 'alignItems' : 'center' , 'margin' : '20px'}}  
            key={user?.login?.uuid} 
        >
            <img  
              style={{'borderRadius':'30px' , 'marginRight' : '20px'}} 
              src={user?.picture?.thumbnail} alt='thumbnail'  />
            <span>{user?.name?.first} {user?.name?.last} </span>
        </li>
    ))
  return (
    <div>
        <h5>UserList</h5>
        <ul style={{ 'listStyleType' : 'none' }} >
            {displayList}
        </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

My test file is as follows where I'm testing if the mock data is getting populated

```
//Body.test.js

import { render, screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react"
import Body from "../Body"
import { usersList } from "../utils/constants";

test('user list should appear on screen', async ()=>{

    global.fetch = jest.fn(()=>{
        return Promise.resolve({
            json : () => {
                return Promise.resolve(usersList)
            }
        })
    })

    render(<Body  />)

    await waitFor(()=>expect(screen.getByTestId("reload-button")))
    const usersArray = screen.getAllByTestId("users-list")
    expect(usersArray.length).toBe(5)
})
```

What is the mistake that I'm doing?

Comment: Have you checked out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67653566/react-jest-testing-testinglibraryelementerror-unable-to-find-an-element?

Comment: Yes, I did see this. In my case, I've a strong feeling that the issue is due to async calls